# How can I fix this error Access violation reading location 0x00000008

Tags: c++, null

First-chance exception at 0x00814477 in Only time for one more.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000008.
Unhandled exception at 0x00814477 in Only time for one more.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000008.

//I believe this has something to do with NULL and the OS but I am unsure how to fix this

```
GameObject::GameObject()
{
    sprite = NULL;
    pos.x = 0; pos.y = 0;
    vel.x = 0; vel.y = 0;

    framenum  = 0;
    numframes = 0;
}

GameObject::~GameObject()
{
    if ( sprite != NULL )
        SDL_FreeSurface( sprite );
}   

void GameObject::LoadImage(std::string filename)
{
    sprite = IMG_Load( filename.c_str() );
    //clip.x = 0;
    //clip.y = 0;
    clip.w = sprite->w;           //It breaks here 
    clip.h = sprite->h;          // and here 
}
```

Comment: The IMG_Load is returning Null because it doesn't have access to the image you're trying to load. You should also post how you implemented the actual function because you may have incorrectly entered the filename. I don't know much about SDL but it may not support all image types and may be throwing this error because it cannot load the file type you've specified.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a very specific bug in the code and is not likely to help future visitors.  This is what "Too Localized" used to be for.

Answer (score 6):

This function call:

```
sprite = IMG_Load( filename.c_str() );
```

Is likely returning `NULL`.  You should check the relevant documentation for why that might be and correct the related error.

Comment: Thank you for the response I am still new to C++ and even newer to SDL and I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 5):

Sprite seems to be null. Check the return of IMG_Load. Most likely your filename isn't correct.